# Why is using a lambda with generics in .NET 7 so slow in WebAssembly?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, webassembly

The following method runs pretty fast in WebAssembly (WASM):

```
public static int SumInt(int[] vals)
{
    int sum = default;

    for (int i = 0; i < vals.Length; i++)
        sum += vals[i];

    return sum;
}
```

For the input I gave it it took about 70 ms to compute the sum.

In trying to make this method generic (in order to handle other types), I wrote this:

```
public static T Sum<T>(T[] vals, Func<T, T, T> add) where T : struct
{
    T sum = default;

    for (int i = 0; i < vals.Length; i++)
        sum = add(sum, vals[i]);

    return sum;
}
```

So that for integers, I can define the following method:

```
public static int Sum(int[] vals) => Sum(vals, (x, y) => x + y);
```

However, for the same input as before, it took about 1000 ms to compute the sum.

When I'm not running this code in WebAssembly but in a .NET application, they both take about the same amount of time.

Any ideas of what's going on or suggestions for improving the code in order to handle other types in a performant way (but also avoid code duplication)?

**More Details**

With the generic `Sum` above, I can also define it for other specific types:

```
public static float Sum(float[] vals) => Sum(vals, AddOp);

public static double Sum(double[] vals) => Sum(vals, AddOp);
```

Comment: Have you tried Ahead-of-time (AOT) compilation for the Blazor/WebAssembly code? Does it make a difference?

Comment: @PaulG Yes, the project has the property `RunAOTCompilation` set to `true`.

Comment: out of interest, what kind of types will you give into this method? So like is it just gonna be ints and doubles for example, or will there be some out there types? And how many numbers have you given the method in your test case?

Comment: Also whats the time you get when you calculate the second time?

Comment: And there already is a generic Sum method for arrays, so why are you trying to write your own?

Comment: @SMSTJ The types I will use with `Sum` are primitive types (like `float` and `double`). For my timing tests, I'm calling the method 100 times with 1,000,000 numbers each. I'm not sure what you mean by "the second time" (running the same tests right after or refreshing the webpage)? I'm not familiar with any generic Sum method other than LINQ, which I just timed and it is about 250 ms.

Comment: @redcurry well the second time thing just took care of itself with the 100 iterations. Ill take some deeper looks

Comment: I assume you are using Blazor?

Comment: @SMSTJ Yes, but it's really stripped down. I have a JavaScript method that calls my C# method and it simply outputs to the Console.

Comment: @redcurry Ok got just wanted to now what base we are working with. I am heading out but what happens when you create a cs file for the razor page and then use you webassembly method to call that?

Comment: @SMSTJ It is so stripped down, there isn't even a Razor page. index.html calls my main.js script, and it in turns calls my C# method.

Comment: @redcurry what suprises me is that you said that in Net both run at the same speed. But when I run both in Net I the generic takes about double the time ( get 509 and 212 but the fact that the values are higher in general is probably just due to processor power) and that double diference is kept everytime. So that means that the basic SumInt also takes significantly longer in Webassembly then in Net (5669 and 2637). Would it be possible for you to show us how exactly you are calling theese in WebAssembly or rather do you use the JSExport to be able to call it in js or do you do something else?

Comment: @SMSTJ To be sure, are you running your tests in Release mode?

Comment: @redcurry yes, but id really like for you to run both versions in the same method and tell me their time in you assembly. I know you already gave me some times but I just wanna have a look. But I do defenetly see that things in wasm are WAY slower. But id also like to see how you run this. I for my test case built in along theese lines 
https://www.meziantou.net/using-dotnet-code-from-javascript-using-webassembly.htm

Comment: @SMSTJ Yes, that's pretty much how I'm running it. I also have the <RunAOTCompilation> property set to true.

Comment: @SMSTJ  I re-ran both versions of `Sum` and the one using generics took 1128 ms, while the one without (`SumInt`) took 73 ms.

Comment: @redcurry  Ok thanks Ill take deeper looks into it but i have to say so far im stuck. Do you use JSExport only on a method that calls your Sum Method, or do you Use JSExport on your Sum Methods themselves?

Comment: @SMSTJ JSExport is used only on one method that then calls the Sum methods. The Sum methods don't have JSExport applied.

Comment: @redcurry have you been able to make some progress?

Comment: @SMSTJ I haven't.